# Unity3D Move Camera with mouse on HORIZONTAL axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was just writing this little piece of code:

```
public float sensitivity = 5.0f;
public float smoothing = 2.0f;
Vector2 smoothV;
Vector2 mouseLook;

GameObject character;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    character = transform.parent.gameObject; 
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


    var mouse = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));
    mouse = Vector2.Scale(mouse, new Vector2(sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));

    smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.x, mouse.x, 1f / smoothing);
    smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.y, mouse.y, 1f / smoothing);
    mouseLook += smoothV;

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
    character.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseLook.x, character.transform.up);
}
```

And it works pretty fine except moving the camera on the horizontal axis. I think with the Initialisation of the Gameobject is something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You said moving camera but your code shows that you are attempting to rotate the object instead....Which one? Rotate or move?

Comment: So when I move the mouse at Verticle Axis, I just dont want to rotate the whole object. When I move the mouse horizontally I want to move the whole object.

Comment: While moving, does the object have to be at the position of the mouse ?

Comment: I dont think so. Its basically A Fps basic controller to control a capsule cameras mouse movement.

Comment: Sorry. I haven't seen any instance where mouse is used to horizontally move the camera in a Fps game. Camera is usually moved with w,a,s,d keys.  I think I don't understand your question and can't answer. Please modify your question and give an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: ouhh. Not moving the camera itself... just rotating it. sorry for bad explaining of my question. My main language isnt english.

Comment: Thanks a lot... And can you explain exactly what your code does? Because I only put code from other people in my projects which i 100 % understand.

Comment: by the code i mean this: xRotCounter += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xMoveThreshold * Time.deltaTime;
        yRotCounter += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * yMoveThreshold * Time.deltaTime;
        yRotCounter = Mathf.Clamp(yRotCounter, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-yRotCounter, xRotCounter, 0);

Comment: `xRotCounter += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")` will increment the rotation with value from the input/mouse. `yRotCounter = Mathf.Clamp` will clamp/limit the rotation to the provided values in the Clamp function.  The limit is there because in a real FPS game, there is a limit of how much you can rotate the camera in the x-axis. `transform.localEulerAngles` is used to assign the value that is clamped.